# Run sonarsouce report plugin through maven

Tags: sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonar-maven-plugin

How can i run **sonarsource report plugin** through maven command for generating sonar analysis reports?

I know the way to do it through sonar-runner, but can we do it directly through mvn command ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured all the properties of your sonar analysis in pom.xml, then you just need to run

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

The [Maven configuration](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Analyzing+with+Maven) may be helpful for this.